# Mac Deleting Multiple Files Bash

Tags: macos, bash, shell, uninstallation

I'm trying to uninstall a program by deleting all of the files the installer installed. This is the script I have tried, but it returns a "`Too many arguments`" error on line `6` (highlighted with `**`) when I try and run it.

This is to be deployed out to multiple machine through [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/).

I would like to put it in a package to run, but as an executable script will also do the job. Am I going about this wrong? This is not the entire script but it follows the same pattern.

```
#!/bin/bash

## This will uninstall ETC Nomad v2.3.3.9.0.10.mpkg
## From Contents of ETCnomad Eos Mac 2.3.3.9.0.10.pkg

**if [ -d /Applications/Eos Family Welcome Screen.app ]; then**
/bin/rm -rf /Applications/Eos Family Welcome Screen.app
fi

if [ -f /tmp/Element_Hotkeys.pdf ]; then
/bin/rm -rf /tmp/Element_Hotkeys.pdf
fi

if [ -f /tmp/Eos_Hotkeys.pdf ]; then
/bin/rm -rf /tmp/Eos_Hotkeys.pdf
fi

if [ -f /tmp/FixtureReleaseNotes.pdf ]; then
/bin/rm -rf /tmp/FixtureReleaseNotes.pdf
fi

if [ -f usr/local/etc/DCIDTable ]; then
/bin/rm -rf usr/local/etc/DCIDTable
fi

exit 0
```

Comment: Try putting `'` around the path/filenames with spaces; avoid using absolute paths and use `rm` only. Also, have you considered using [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) for Mac?

Comment: Use [AppCleaner](http://appcleaner.en.softonic.com/mac) instead.

Comment: Should have included this in the original post, this is to be used in a production environment for removing it from not just one machine, deployed out through ARD. AppCleaner won't work.

Comment: @Jens Why avoid absolute paths ?

Comment: `if [ -f <path> ]; then rm -rf <path>; fi` is an antipattern. In particular, it can lead to race conditions. Simpy use `rm -rf <path>` instead.

Comment: @TomSmith Why are you working on a production system if you are new to scripting ?

Comment: @123: Because it's the job of the shell to find the appropriate commands using the `PATH` environment variable. Absolute paths can cause problems when the host installation is different and then your script isn't portable. In my case, for example, I use MacPorts with its own `rm` command in a different folder, but all scripts run because my shell environment handles command paths.

Comment: @Jubobs how could it lead to a race condition if the second part is dependant on the first ?

Comment: @123 Another process could create/remove the file right after the test, before the body of the if statement executes.

Comment: @Jens Relative paths can be troublesome as well if you ever want to move anything though. Is it not better to use variables that equate to absolute paths ?

Comment: @Jubobs Ahh right i thought you meant within the command, thanks :)

Comment: @123: I did not say to use relative paths, I said to use no paths but the command only. The `PATH` environment variable should provide enough information to the shell to find the command. That's what it's there for.

Comment: @123 Thought I would give it a try, I've got the package installing through Filewave and thought it would be useful to have an uninstaller if it is ever needed. More of a personal project to learn more about scripting really.

Comment: @Jens Ahh, you were talking about rm. I misread your first comment and thought you meant don't use full paths for any of it, not just rm. soz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Answer*

Use `'` around path/filenames that contain spaces or else the shell will try to interpret the parts as different from the filename and get confused, hence the error message.

*More comments*

- As jubobs points out, there's no use in testing whether the file exists before deleting it. Furthermore, you already use the [`-f`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rm) option which ignores nonexistent files so the test becomes irrelevant.
- Remove absolute paths from your commands to the keep your script portable. The shell's `PATH` environment variable is used to search for commands in the right places.
- No need to remove files from `/tmp/` because the OS does that for you.
- Be careful when you tinker with system folders like `/usr/` because every system upgrades overwrite them, and often times it's hard to tell all dependencies.

You can simplify your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

## This will uninstall ETC Nomad v2.3.3.9.0.10.mpkg
## From Contents of ETCnomad Eos Mac 2.3.3.9.0.10.pkg

rm -rf '/Applications/Eos Family Welcome Screen.app'
# rm -rf /tmp/Element_Hotkeys.pdf
# rm -rf /tmp/Eos_Hotkeys.pdf
# rm -rf /tmp/FixtureReleaseNotes.pdf
rm -rf /usr/local/etc/DCIDTable

exit 0
```

Comment: The os may not remove files from tmp for days, weeks, months or years, depending on various factors. If the files are big, it might make sense to explicitly remove them instead of waiting for the next reboot, or the next time a process runs to clean up /tmp.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Agreed.

Comment: Fortunatly the only files I am targeting are installed by the program, I'm using Pacifist to open up the package and target the specific files it installs. Worked great, thanks.